# How to align a floating div to the right of a table cell, outside said table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table.

I'm trying to have an element **external** to that table, that is **vertically aligned to one of the table lines**.

Like in this picture:
[magic magic table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWKn4.png)

To the left you can see the table (the blank lines are still part of the table itself, it's one long table).

To the right, near the bottom, you can see an external div, which is to be aligned to the `tr` to its left.

I understand the solution might involve using `position: relative` in said external div, but for the life of me I'm failing to get the correct combination of properties.

If I just put the `div` inside the `th` and then I move it with `left: XX` it will move relative to the *center* of the `th`, not to its right. I need to say "`div`, you should be positioned XX pixels relative **to the right end** of this `td`".

So far, I've no clue how.

Any help, please?

---

html:

```
    <tr class="title">
            <th colspan=3 class="center">
                Match #13
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="show_clashes( 13 );">Show clashes</button>
                <br>
                2016-11-04 00:00:00 ~ 2016-11-04 23:59:59

    <div class="clashes" id="match_clashes-13" style="display:none;">

        <table class="std">
```

css:

```
div.clashes {
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to put the `div` inside said `th`, and move it to the right, but as it is id doesn't do what I meant it to do (in the picture I manually moved it to the correct place).

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the table a set width? Like:

```
table {
    width: 75%;
}
```

If that doesn't work could you include your code so I can see more of what you are talking about?

Comment: I'd rather not have to depend on such a limitation, if possible. I'd assume this can be done, if only you know how. Code posted, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried messing with display? Such as making everything `display: block;`.

Comment: A bit, but nothing happened. Anyway, even if I was ok with setting a table with a set width, how could that help?

Comment: I'm still a little confused at what you want to do. Your picture wasn't very clear. But have you tried putting the other content in a div and floating it left? Maybe you could draw a basic sketch of what you want to do?